# How to run multiple functions against series using panda_udf

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large number of image files that have been encoded from binary. I am trying to decode them and then save them to hdfs. I have code the does this successfully in python but because of the large number of files needing to be done it doesn't make sense to have to import everything, convert to a panda, then run my code even if it would all fit on a single node as a panda which it won't. I've been trying to convert my code from a panda function to a pyspark panda_udf but without success. Below is my code. if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

```
def image_save(bin,file):
    start = datetime.now()
    b64_encoded_img_binary = bin
    img_binary = np.fromstring(b64_encoded_img_binary.decode('base64'), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_binary, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imwrite('/dsaa/ml_shared/image_output/'+ str(file).replace(' ','').replace('JPEG','jpg'), img)
    end = datetime.now()
    time = (end - start).total_seconds()
    return time

df['seconds'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
image_save(x['b64_encoded_image_binary'],x['file_name']), axis=1)
```

The code works with a panda and saves the files correctly. But when I try to wrap the code with @pandas_udf I get an error that it expects a series to return instead of a float. I know that scalar pandas udf outputs a series, but I'm at a loss to figure out how to make the code changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this one. I didn't think to take the next logical step that a panda is composed of series. So it make it work I could take the series inputs and make them a dataframe within the function.

```
def FPD(a, b):

    def F2(a, b):
        c = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(a.decode('base64'), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imwrite('/dsaa/ml_shared/image_output/' + b, c)
        return(b)

    pdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b' : b })
    pdf.loc[:, 'c'] = pdf.apply(lambda x: F2(x['a'], x['b']), axis = 1)
    return(b)
```